# Determine the Guest OS version of an Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure-cloud-services

How does one determine the Guest OS version running on a Cloud Service? I cannot find this info exposed in either the Old (https://manage.windowsazure.com) or New (https://portal.azure.com) Azure Portal.

My Cloud Services are setup to use "*" as the osVersion so I realize the Guest OS gets updated as new versions are released. I just want to know what version I am currently running.

You might ask why I need to know? Well currently I want to know if my VMs are running the new Guest OS that supports .NET v4.5.2. But the broader question still applies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can browse to the Cloud Service resource using https://resources.azure.com. That will reveal the OSVersion property.

It also reveals the PowerShell command to retrieve it, which should be similar to this:\

```
Get-AzureRmResource –ResourceGroupName <name> –ResourceType Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/slots/roles –ResourceName <cloudservicename/slot/rolename> –ApiVersion 2015-06-01 | select –ExpandProperty Properties | select OsVersion
```